# How to wrork with Hibernate entity relationship

Tags: hibernate

I learning Hibernate with "Begining Hibernate", I do all examples but I can not understand how to work with them. I need a normal example to understand and learn how to apply this in practice (1to1, 1:m, m:n).
Help me please. the book shows a lot of things and I'm just confused.

Answer (score 0):

For one to one Mapping, visit 
https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-1.html

For one to many mapping, visit 
https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html

For many to many mapping, visit
https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-1.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.